# Infinite recursion in decorator (Class seems to inherit from itself)

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I'm seeing an infinite recursion in a decorated class:

```
def my_decorator():
    def class_decorator(cls):
        class NewClass(cls):
            @classmethod
            def func(cls):
                print "decorator"
                super(NewClass, cls).func()

        return NewClass
    return class_decorator

class B(object):
    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        print "Root"

@my_decorator()
class A(B):
    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        print "func"
        super(A, cls).func()


x = A()    
x.func()
```

Outputs:

```
decorator
func
func
func
func
... <lots of 'func'> ...
lots of these:
  File "test.py", line 22, in func
    super(A, cls).func()
  File "test.py", line 22, in func
    super(A, cls).func()
  File "test.py", line 22, in func
    super(A, cls).func()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Without the decorator, it returns:

```
func
Root
```

...as expected.

What's going on?

Comment: That does seem odd; `A.__mro__` is `(<class '__main__.NewClass'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)`, which I'd expect, so it isn't clear why `super(A, cls)` is resolving to `A` again...

Comment: Ah, I know why - it's because `A` isn't `A`, it's `NewClass`, whose parent is `A`, which isn't `A`, it's `NewClass`, whose parent is `A`, ...

Comment: Aha!  That makes sense! Now I need to work out what to do about it.  I can directly reference the superclass, I wonder if there's a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've decorated the original `A`, which is equivalent to:

```
A = my_decorator()(A)
```

The name `A` refers to the newly created `NewClass`, which also inherits from the original `A`, **not** the original `A`. Therefore `super(A, cls).func` always resolves to `super(NewClass, cls).func`, which is `A.func`.

Unwrapping the decorator and assigning the result to a *different* name, you get the correct behaviour:

```
X = my_decorator()(A)
x = X()
x.func()
```

gives:

```
decorator
func
Root
```

Answer (score 0):

Code like this:

```
@my_decorator()
class A(B):
# ...
```

is semantically the same thing as:

```
A = my_decorator(A)
```

(according to [PEP 3129](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/))

That means that the symbol with name `A`, which normally would hold a Type value of 'class A' is actually being *redefined* to be whatever is returned from `my_decorator`, which is the Type `NewClass`.

So at the point where you call

```
 super(A, cls).func()
```

`A` actually refers to `NewClass` (as does `cls`), resulting in a call to the same method.